# Improve read performance in Cassandra using the spark connector - GC tuning but not only

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, cassandra-3.0

I am writing here to have some advices on how to improve read performance in a analytics job using the spark-cassandra connector.
I am facing are some timeout issues while performing lots of reads on several partition keys.

In cassandra logs such timeouts are something like:

```
WARN  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2017-12-06 04:31:49,752 MonitoringTask.java:150 - 32 operations timed out in the last 20394 msecs, operation list available at debug log level
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2017-12-06 04:31:49,753 MonitoringTask.java:155 - 32 operations timed out in the last 20394 msecs:
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE ts = 2017-11-10 00:32+1100 LIMIT 5000: total time 15563 msec - timeout 5000 msec
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE ts = 2017-10-20 00:31+1100 LIMIT 5000: total time 15597 msec - timeout 5000 msec
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE ts = 2017-10-20 00:49+1100 LIMIT 5000: total time 15596 msec - timeout 5000 msec
```

### The cluster

I am running an analytic Spark job in a cluster with this configuration:

- DC1: 2 nodes, both with 32 cores and 64GB of RAM
- DC2: 2 nodes with 32 and 24 cores, both with 64GB of RAM

On all nodes I run Cassandra and Spark.
As spark jobs, I have a streaming job and the the analytic job (running once a day).
The replication factor is 2, one per DC. This is configured to have one copy of each data per DC.
All nodes have C* 3.7 and Spark 2.1.1, connector version 2.0.5.

The spark streaming job is in charge of the writes in the cluster (it receives data from Flume agent). This means that my cluster have a heavy write workload throughout all the day, and a heavy read workload once a day.

### The table read

The table I am reading data from has this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz (
    ts timestamp,
    f1 text,
    f2 text,
    count counter,
    PRIMARY KEY ((ts), f1, f2)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (f1 ASC, f2 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

As you can see, the partition key is ts, where each possible value represent a particular minute in time (for example, 2017-12-05 17:42+0000)

### The analytics job

I run the analytic job with 2 executors per node, 4 cores per executor, 5GB per executor (32 cores and 40GB of memory in total).

The analytical job is in charge of reading data from one C* table and write to another C* table (with a different partition key).

The analytic job reads 12 weeks of data in 24 batches reading each 5040 minutes, thus accessing 5040 partition keys.
For each batch, I prepare a RDD with the 5040 keys, and then I use `repartitionByCassandraReplica` with `joinWithCassandraTable` to ensure data locality.

From `nodetool tablestats` and `nodetool tablehistograms` I can see that a partition size is, on average, 422KB. This means that each batch need to read 5040*422KB ~= 2GB of (uncompressed?) data.

The jobs connects to the master node, as I do not specify the host in the C* connector.
For this reason, by default, data will be read only from DC1.

### The problem

With the default Cassandra Heap space size of 8GB, the spark job fails due to many read timeouts errors in C*.
I was able to correlate these errors with big GC pauses due to FullGC.

I investigated a lot, and I was able to exclude peaks in disk access (with iostat command). 
Tracing the same kind of queries in CQLSH I was able to see a reasonable response time (10-50ms) for more than a thousand request done at the same time.

The sole issue seems to be the Garbage Collector.

I tried to increase MAX_HEAP_MEMORY from 8 to 12GB, and then from 12GB to 16GB. It helped but still see some timeouts:

- With 8GB, as mentioned, the job stopped as there were too many timeouts that cause spark errors
- With 12GB the job completed in 48 minutes, with around 15-20 timeouts due to GC visible in Cassandra log only (no impact on spark job)
- With 16GB the job completed in 41 minutes, **still with** some timeouts due to GC (around 10 cases)

**First question:** would it be useful to override the connector parameter `spark.cassandra.connection.factory` to use a policy that will use all the nodes from both DC considering that my latency between DC is low (< 3ms)?

This will put less pressure on the nodes on DC1, as the reads will be spread on 4 nodes instead of 2.

**Second question:** considering the way the data is written on the table, I might decide to change the compaction strategy to `DateTieredCompactionStrategy`. Would it be useful to change the compaction strategy?

This is a costly operation in a production cluster, so I would like to be reasonably sure that it will be beneficial.
For information, I can see that the number of SSTables accessed on different nodes is between 5 and 12 for the 50% percentile, 7 and 14 for 99% and 7-14 again as max value (from `nodetool tablehistograms`)

**Third question:** is there another optimisation point I am missing here?

Comment: 1) did you do a cassandra-stress test on DC1 ? how does the read latency look? 2) what is the resources availability to the write job and cassandra when analytics job is running?

Comment: please can you run analytics job WITHOUT repartionWithCassandraReplica and put results here?

Comment: @abpan you can follow the discussion I had in the datastax mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/PaQm1LT7Qlk)